# CPP Guessing Game not working, its stops after i enter the name

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

I'm trying to make this kina guess game on C++, I'm a beginner and still learning.
What I'm trying to achieve is a guessing game of two const names, is very simple without errors but it's not working after I enter something. it should report until I find the correct name. Please also I don't want to change the structure of the code, just find why isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Vlerat {
    string guess01 = "Resul";
    string guess02 = "Rejan";
    int numruesi = 0;
};

int main() {
    Vlerat funksioni;
    string nameGuess;
    int nameOkay = 0;
    cout << "Gjej njerin prej dy emrava te fshehura." << endl;
    cout << "Ndihm: Fillojn me Shkronjen 'R', dhe pas asaj vjen edhe nje shkronj 'e'" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Shkruaj Emrin > "; cin >> nameGuess;

        if (nameGuess == funksioni.guess01){
            cout << "Ju e keni gjetur emrin e njerit nga personat duke provuar gjithesej:";
            cout << funksioni.numruesi++ << " here." << endl;
            nameOkay++;
        }
        if (nameGuess == funksioni.guess02) {
            cout << "Ju e keni gjetur emrin e njerit nga personat duke provuar gjithesej:";
            cout << funksioni.numruesi++ << " here." << endl;
            nameOkay++;
        }
        funksioni.numruesi++;
    } while(nameOkay = 0);
}
```

Comment: `nameOkay = 0` should be `nameOkay == 0`

Comment: `nameOkay = 0` is assignment. `nameOkay == 0` would be comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `while(nameOkay = 0);` to `while(nameOkay == 0);`.
Because `=` is an assignment, but `==` is operator of comparing (equality)

[Read about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/equality-operators-equal-equal-and-exclpt-equal?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017)

[And here](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)